# How can I add icons in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons

I want to add icons like this. [image: Example]

Where can I get these icons?

Answer (score 1):

You can go for third party libraries.

[React Icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons) or [react-icons-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons-kit)